# php code to get previous base name of a directory

Tags: php, directory, root

Please i need to get the previous base-name of a folder i use this code to have it work, but still have not got what i want. bellow is how my link look like.

> http://www.example.net/cjl/PhpLoginPage/images/

```
echo substr(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), 0, strrpos(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), '/') - 1);
```

My output will be like this

`/cjl/PhpLoginPag`

Now my problem is that i don't need to add other thing i need to get the main directory name like this 
`PhpLoginPag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `basename` for this

```
echo basename(dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])));
```